# ¿como traer los datos de una api en un StreamBuilder o en DropdownButtonFormField?

Tags: api, flutter

como puedo traer los datos de una api en un StreamBuilder o en DropdownButtonFormField que me listen los datos que estan en el API  o por medio de TextField y un showGeneralDialog

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, para poder ayudarte a resolver el problema:
1- No pongas screenshots, agrega el código.
2- Agrega un código mínimo que podamos ejecutarlo desde aquí (como ejemplo), para poder corregirlo o indicarte.
3- También podrías agregarlo aquí: https://gist.github.com/ y poner el link

Comment: En todo caso, si el [repro] no cabe en la pregunta, agrega _además_ el enlace externo. Toda la info necesaria para reproducir el problema debe estar _en la pregunta_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Para un dropdow la mejor forma seria utilizar un FutureBuilder

introducir el código aquí

```
  Widget _dropdown() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: provider.functionProvider(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  isDense: true,
                  items: _getdropdownOptions(snapshot.data),
                  onChanged: (opt) {
                    // print(opt);
                    setState(() {
                      _opcionSeleccionada = int.parse(opt.toString());
                    });
                  },
                  validator: (value) =>
                      value == null ? 'campo requerido' : null,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _getdropdownOptions(List<Model> snapshot) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> lista = [];
    for (var element in snapshot) {
      lista.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(
          element.nombre.toString(),
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
        value: element.id.toString(),
      ));
    }

    return lista;
  }
```

introducir el código aquí